# Recording audio data from Flutter (16000Hz PCM data), capturing the audio to send it to backend(Node.js)

Tags: node.js, flutter, post, audio-recording

I am trying to record audio through [mic_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream) package in pub.dev (since I want 16000Hz PCM data), and trying to capture data and send it to Nodejs server. I am not making any changes to the mic_stream example in the provided link, but I want to send the audio data in 16000Hz PCM format to Nodejs server. I have tried using http.MultipartFile as shown below:

```dart
var url = Uri.parse("http://localhost:3000/upload");
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
Future<int> length = stream.length;
var stream_length = http.ByteStream(stream);
request.files.add( await http.MultipartFile('music',stream,length,{
"filename1234.pcm"), new MediaType('audio', 'x-wav')});   
//This gives me error because length is not of int type

request.send().then((response) {
  print("test");
  if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded! ${response}");
  else   print("Failure");
});
```

I want to know if this works or if there are any other packages that I can use to record the data and send to Nodejs in PCM format 16000Hz.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In order to upload something, you need a fixed number of samples (i.e. however many milliseconds of audio), but you have an indefinite stream. This first manifests itself in that to get the length of the stream, you need to `await stream.length`, but that will never complete because the stream isn't finite. First you need to resolve this conflict: how do you take this infinite stream of mic data and gather some of it to send to the server.

Comment: Hi @RichardHeap, Thank you for the prompt reply. I am trying to upload the audio stream after clicking the stop button, so, I guess it's not an infinite stream, please correct me if I am wrong as I am new to flutter programming. I used `await stream.length` but that is giving me exception "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to". Could you please help me with any other way I can try. Since, **http.MultipartFile** can be replaced with **http.MultipartFile.fromBytes**, can I convert the Stream<List<int>> to List<int> and then upload? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, listen to the stream appending each List<int> to your in memory list. Note that the length of the audio is the sum of the lengths of each list you get from the stream (not the length of the stream itself). You may find it easier to use `flutter_audio_recorder` which can create a WAV file, and you could then upload that - depends on whether your server wants a WAV header or not. If you continue with `mic_stream` you need to figure out whether it returns 16 bit ints or pairs of bytes already in a particular endian.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHeap, using flutter_audio_recorder worked. Extremely grateful.